# Typecasting a string with no number, ever produce result > 0?

Tags: php, casting

In `php` I use `(int) $variable` to typecast a value into `INT`.

And my experience by far is as follows..

```
Input              (int) Output
abcd                0
12abcd              12
abcd12              0
'something weird'   <0 ??
```

If I am typecasting "*a string with no numbers/digits in it*", will it ever produce a result greater than 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a string is evaluated in a numeric context, the resulting value
>   and type are determined as follows.
>
> If the string does not contain any of the characters '.', 'e', or 'E'
>   and the numeric value fits into integer type limits (as defined by
>   PHP_INT_MAX), the string will be evaluated as an integer. In all other
>   cases it will be evaluated as a float.
>
> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. **If the string
>   starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used.**
>   **Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero).** Valid numeric data is an
>   optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a
>   decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an
>   'e' or 'E' followed by one or more digits.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)